# Excel Datedif with dates prior to 1900

Tags: excel

How can I calculate the difference between two dates in Excel older than 1900? For example between 05/05/1862 and 04/16/1938. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26582581/62576

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores dates as number of days since 1900, so one option might be to convert them to dates after 1900. For example, if `A1` contains the text `05/05/1862`, then this formula results in `05/05/3862`:

```
= LEFT(A1, 6) & RIGHT(A1, 4) + 2000
```

and the difference in number of days between two text dates can be:

```
= (LEFT(A1, 6) & RIGHT(A1, 4) + 2000) - (LEFT(A2, 6) & RIGHT(A2, 4) + 2000)
```

Comment: Should be better `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+2000, Month(A1), DAY(A1))` to shift a date 2000 years to future. This is independent of the date format used. And you should mention why you think that the difference between two dates remains the same if both dates are shifted 2000 years to future.

Comment: @AxelRichter but `YEAR("05/05/1862")` results in `#VALUE!` error, so the year has to be at least 1900. I am actually not fully sure about the 2000 because of possible adjustments to the Gregorian calendar, but based it off of the leap year every 400 years rule

Comment: Yes you are right, the `05/05/1862` cannot be a date in `Excel` it must be text. My fault. So this is not solvable without knowing the exact date format used. And yes, the 2000 years are one of the good year shifting numbers according to the leap year algorithm. Both should be mentioned in the answer.